# store and udpate svg document

Tags: java, svg

I use `SVG` for drawing hierarchical structures - like genealogy trees for characters.

It looks something like this

```
<svg width="580" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
  <title>background</title>
  <rect fill="#fff" id="canvas_background" height="402" width="582" y="-1" x="-1"/>
  <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="canvasGrid">
   <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect id="svg_1" height="27" width="81" y="54.283333" x="84.5" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/>
  <rect id="svg_4" height="27" width="81" y="54.283333" x="183.5" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/>
  <rect id="svg_5" height="27" width="81" y="130.283333" x="133.5" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/>
  <rect id="svg_6" height="27" width="81" y="130.283333" x="299.5" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="#fff"/>
  <line stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_7" y2="65.283333" x2="185.5" y1="65.283333" x1="165.5" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
  <line stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_8" y2="129.283333" x2="175.5" y1="63.283333" x1="175.5" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
  <line stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_9" y2="140.283333" x2="215.5" y1="140.283333" x1="300.5" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" font-size="24" id="svg_10" y="73.283333" x="87.5" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">mother</text>
  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" font-size="24" id="svg_11" y="75.283333" x="193.5" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">father</text>
  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" font-size="24" id="svg_12" y="150.283333" x="142.5" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">player</text>
  <text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" font-size="24" id="svg_13" y="150.283333" x="317.5" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#000000">npc1</text>
 </g>
</svg>
```

I want to to update this SVG from time to time depending on the changes made in the world by the player or other entities. So ideally I want to have the ability to store it somewhere and update when changes happen.

My question is what is the proper way doing that? Storing SVG as file, parse it and update DOM (with `DOMIMplementation` and `Element` or etc.) or for example store it in some XML database and update using queries or something?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an XML parser to read it as a generic XML file. Then modify that.

Or you could use an SVG implementation, such as Batik, which will give you access to the functionality that the SVG DOM provides.

Comment: But is it really effective to parse XML file every time, change and update it? Though my problem I think is that I am trying to use SVG as a data model instead of just a form of representation